# Refresh Page with JavaScript OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Within my pen, I'd like to refresh my page after each click of a door. Not sure where I should drop the window.location.reload();

Here's the pen

https://codepen.io/tacodestroyer/pen/bROpeQ

```
function openDoor(field) {
        var y = $(field).find(".thumb");
        var x = y.attr("class");
        if (y.hasClass("thumbOpened")) {
            y.removeClass("thumbOpened");
        }
        else {
            $(".thumb").removeClass("thumbOpened");
            y.addClass("thumbOpened");
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you reload the page you might as well not bother setting any of the classes, because they will be reset when the page reloads anyway.

Comment: Why would you want to refresh the page?

Comment: Note that if you reload, there is no use to have a closing door animation...

Comment: Well, Ideally i'd like for an image to show up behind each door, randomized and figured that I'd need to do a refresh to get the next image.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to put random images behind the door, the easiest way would be to create a series of CSS classes for `divs` that have background images then keep those classnames within an array in your JS. Then when you click on a door, you randomly choose one of the items in that array and apply that class the way you're applying the "open door" effect.

Comment: So, working through that, I think this is the path that I'd like to go down but I'm having issues where I should insert that array. Thoughts?

Comment: Well, you could do it many ways. If this truly is an isolated example, much like a homework assignment, you could keep it all in the same function. Written as an _array literal_, it'd be as simple as `var myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];` then later you would generate a "random" number that would represent the index to choose from your list of classnames; in this case being "one", "two", and "three".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the opening-door animation to complete before reloading the page. You could use the `transitionend` event for that:

```
function openDoor(field) {
    var y = $(field).find(".thumb");
    var x = y.attr("class");
    if (y.hasClass("thumbOpened")) {
    // NB: This might never happen given that you reload the page once you open a door
        y.removeClass("thumbOpened");
    }
    else {
        $(".thumb").removeClass("thumbOpened");
        y.addClass("thumbOpened");
        // Wait for the animation to end:
        $(".thumb").on("transitionend", function() {
            // ... and then reload, or do whatever else you want to happen next
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }
}
```